# Prisma Client Mocking with jest: TypeError: mock.mockReset is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, prisma

I am getting the following error, when trying to mock a PrismaClient.

"TypeError: mock.mockReset is not a function", when it hits the beforeEach/ mockReset function.

The code I have is pretty simple.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import {  mockDeep, DeepMockProxy, mockReset} from 'jest-mock-extended'

import { prisma } from './client'

jest.mock('./client', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
}))

beforeEach(() => {
    mockReset(prismaMock)
  })


export const prismaMock = prisma as unknown as DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>
```

The code I have in the client file is also quite simple:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

export const prismaClient = new PrismaClient()
export const prisma = prismaClient
```

Comment: Sort of fixed the issue, in that my code was running tests on both the TS files, and the compiled JS files.  

It was only the complied JS files that were failing, so when I stopped unnecessarily testing those, it worked.

Comment: export const prisma = prismaClient doesn't really do anything, may want to consider removing that.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Update the mock to match the specified exports:

```
jest.mock('./client', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  prisma: mockDeep<PrismaClient>()
}))
```

### Explanation

The mocked exports are not lining up with the actual files exports:

**Client File**

```
export const prisma = prismaClient; // named export: "prisma"
```

**Mock Of The Client File**

```
jest.mock('./client', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(), // default export which needs to match the named export ('prisma')
}))
```

So when jest tries to reset the mock, it's looking call `.mockReset` on  a named export called "prisma", which you're setting up here, but it doesn't exist (hence the not a function error): it exists on the default export instead.